# How to prevent logback from emitting repeated "Empty watch file list. Disabling" messages

Tags: logback

I have logback configured with the logback.xml located here: http://pastebin.com/KuqUEkXy.

Every minute, I see a log message emitted of the form:

18:26:21,486 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1478715201485) - Empty watch file list. Disabling

Why is this happening and how can I get rid of these?

Comment: I assume the watch list is the set of files being watched for changes and that the scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds" are what are causing the ReconfigureOnChangeTask to run every minute. However, given that there *is* a logback.xml (inside a jar) and that I saw a log message during configuration to the effect "Will scan for changes in [jar:file:/path/to/example.jar!/logback.xml]" that there is (at least) one file to watch. So why the empty watch list messages?

Answer (score 9):

I can tell you why this is happening, but not how to get rid of them.

The `ReconfigureOnChangeTask` will [log this line](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/joran/ReconfigureOnChangeTask.java#L48) when it doesn't have any files to watch.

And it doesn't have any files to watch because the file is in a jar, and it will [only watch files on the filesystem](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/ConfigurationWatchList.java#L94). This makes sense, because files within a jar file generally don't change.

Answer (score 8):

Just remove the scan="true" in the first line of configuration

Answer (score 5):

In your logback configuration (logback.xml), you have to turn OFF (or better, just remove) the scan attributes in the configuration element

Comment: Thanks for your first post on StackOverflow! Double thanks for taking on an answer first. Consider reading about how to best answer a question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 5):

1. This problem occurred due to scan attribute in logback configuration. If you are not going to change your log level runtime, remove **scan and scanPeriod** attribute from configuration.
2. If you want to change log level runtime, you need to configure **scan and scanPeriod** attribute in logback.xml.

To resolve the problem, we have two option.

1. If your logback.xml **configuration** tag contain **debug="true"** scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds". Remove **debug="true"** from configuration.

If you still face problem, you can perform below approach.

2. Override **OnConsoleStatusListener**

Configure the below line in logback.xml

```
<statusListener class="com.example.CustomOnConsoleStatusListener"/>

import ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener;
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.Status;
public class CustomOnConsoleStatusListener extends OnConsoleStatusListener {
    @Override
    public void addStatusEvent(Status status) {
        
        if (!status.getMessage().contains("Empty watch file list. Disabling"))
            super.addStatusEvent(status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possibly by overriding the logback.xml from jar file by a file in filesystem. Instead of runnnig jar the main class should be called.

Suppose we have a jar file with the manifest:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
...
Main-Class: a.b.c.jetty.MyMainClass
```

Call the MyMainClass:

```
java -cp path2logbackXml:path2jarfile a.b.c.MyMainClass
```

instead of

```
java -jar path2jarfile
```